# How to get status of network interfaces?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, networking, interface, wifi

How can I detect the status of wifi, cellular and bluetooth in my program? I know that I can check network availability with NetworkInterface. But how can I check for each kind?

When I am in wifi mode I still want to know if cellular network is available...

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to Microsoft.Phone (if it's not already added by default), then refer to [Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation_members%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), which will tell you about the status of Bluetooth, Cellular connectivity, WiFi, and the name of the mobile operator.

Comment: Thank you, so I was pretty close. But there is no Bluetooth status?